# Drupal Language Switcher menu item

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I am using D 7.28 with Boostrap theme (https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). 
I am using the theme's 'Main menu' to display my links. The language switcher works well for me (changing homepage, Hero banner block and navigation into the appropriate language).

I would like to move the language switcher to the 'Main menu' and display it as an item only showing the inactive language.

Could anyone please provide instructions how to do it?

[image: D7 language switcher]

Comment: See: http://milhaus.wikidot.com/materialy:jak-na-language-switcher-v-bootstrapu

Answer (score 1):

I have a small module hosted on GitHub that does just that:

[Locale Menu](https://github.com/balsama/localemenu)

From the README file:

> ### Overview
>
> Alters the href of any menu item whose title is "English" or "Español" to point to the translated version of the current menu item. If no translation exists for the current menu item, the link will point to the translated version of the homepage.

You'll need to tweak Lines 6, 15, and (especially) 21 of the localemenu.module file to match the name and language code of your language.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a module that provides a language switcher dropdown for Bootstrap-enabled themes. It is available as a sandbox module here: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pascalanimateur/2493639

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.